# EMC-EFT problem with touch screen

Tags: emc, tft

Before taking this job, I had never been in a laboratory and did not know these topics. Moreover, when the chief engineer left work, all the testing was left to me. This device passed RE and CE side but failed on immunity side. The device is medical device so we are using 60601-1 compatible power supply. The device is class II so there is no earth connection. The device has temperature measuring, LEDs, some analog reads and TFT color screen.

The main PCB and the keypad PCB of the TFT color display are in different places, so there are two PCBs. There is not much on the PCB of this TFT color screen. It has a 3x3 push button matrix and SPI connection. This SPI connection is connected to the main PCB via ribbon cable.

When the EFT test (61000-4-4, 2 kV 100 kHz) first starts, random buttons work. So, for example, the device presses the menu button and goes to the main menu, then the screen does not turn off, but none of the buttons work. The important point here is that the TFT color screen does not turn off and the treatment time on the screen continues to increase smoothly, but the button works at first and then does not work.

Push buttons are controlled in a 3x3 matrix with a 10 kΩ resistor in each column (3 in total, 1 for each column). I added 0.1 uF and 10 uF to these buttons and tried again but it failed. I reduced the resistor value and added 0.1 uF and 10 uF, it made a better difference for 30 seconds, but it failed again.

The important point here is that when the EFT test started, SW7 SW8 and SW9 buttons worked.

[image]

- Should I add capacitor on these pin? Does it help?
- If I add ferrite choke to the ribbon cable, will it help?

I can't think of anything else, can you please let me know if you have any suggestions? I can also try these suggestions in the laboratory.

The pushbuttons connected to the PIC microcontroller's IO pins:

[image]

The SPI connection for the TFT colour screen:

[image]

Comment: Please show a block diagram of the overall system, including how and where EFT is being applied; and a schematic of the MCU(?) and keypad/matrix area at least. Preferably complete schematics and assembly diagrams.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added.

Comment: Thank you for the added content. Some questions: is the power supply not connected to anything? I see a ribbon cable photo between "MAIN PCB" and "KEYBOARD PCB" implying a connection, but no line connecting to the power supply. (I'll assume EFT TESTER includes a coupling network and provides mains power to the supply.) What are the SPI-style signals in the schematic? They don't connect to anything else; it's not clear what purpose they serve, nor where they go (or if their names are more than coincidental). Likewise the pushbuttons, what do they connect to?

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry for these. I updated again.

Comment: Are all your mF actually uF perchance?

Comment: Is the unwanted behavior only present when exposed to susceptibility testing or does it persist afterwards?

Comment: @Lundin we couldn't go further. We passed RE and CE sides but for immunity side, it fails on test 1 and tests stopped. As I said, when the test device is turned on during the testing phase, one of the SW7 or SW8 or SW9 buttons works, but then the buttons are not detected.

Comment: @winny yes it is 100nf so 0.1 uF. I wrote wrong.

Comment: So it isn't necessarily the buttons themselves that are the problem, could as well be the MCU? Maybe it went into low-voltage reset?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think the problem is MCU because device has treatment time. I can see the screen and it counts well. Thats why I am thinking only the problem push button side. I might be wrong but as I said, the microcontroller counts the time and I can see it on the TFT screen even push button not works.

Comment: Maybe you could add your debounce source code to the question?

Comment: @Lundin, I have to ask my manager to share it. Can software cause this problem? If i increase the keypad read time, maybe it will help.

Comment: If the debounce algorithm is poorly written or non-existent, then yes that will be a problem. Or if it was written in a super naive way using GPIO interrupts. If debouncing isn't handled in software, then you have to add external RC filters to each input. Which as it turns out also, works nicely for filtering some (low frequency) EMI and ESD.

Comment: @Lundin I just looked at the code and a delay was added by decreasing the integer values ​​in the button readings.  With Interrupt, the treatment time is kept.

Comment: What kind of interrupt? Timer interrupt or GPIO port interrupt?

Comment: @Lundin It has Timer0 interrupt enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing much more detail of the circuit and what actually fails it's very hard to say.

I would start off by adding transient suppression from each signal where it enters the PCB (so if there's a cable to the 3x3 matrix and/or display, the suppressors need to be at the PCB end of that cable before the signal is routed to any other component).

Now any induced voltage should get shunted to GND through the suppressor.

Look for TVS diodes as a starting point.  Unidirectional ones are ok and you obviously need them to have a zener voltage higher than your logic voltages so that in normal operation the diodes are not conducting.

Edit: I would place the TVS diodes on LINEx and COLUMNx signals on the main PCB next to the ribbon cable connector.  The switches are more or less impossible to damage with emc so they don't need protection.  Note that this won't make the buttons 'work' during the test but it will prevent damage to the MCU.   If your goal is to have the buttons work during the test then you need to understand what is going wrong in more detail.  You have just said that it 'does not work', but not explained what the MCU is actually seeing in terms of GPIO levels.  It might very well be worth shielding the ribbon cable with, for example, some copper foil and then connecting that to GND at the main PCB only.   And finally your EFT might not be generating EMC at all, it might just be disturbing the power on the board in a way that corrupts the MCU state.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added new photos about PCB's. The important point here is that when the EFT test started, SW7 SW8 and SW9 buttons worked.
I also look for TVS diode and it might be work thank you but where should I place them ? Since sw7,sw8 and sw9 buttons works, should I place TVS diode parallel to 10k resistors ? Or Should I place TVS diode on Ribbon cable ? (Which side mian pcb or keyboard pcb?)

Comment: Depending on field levels required in the test, then it might be sufficient to simply add series resistors to the input pins. But if this is a medical device I would guess it is tested somewhere around 100V/m which is pretty tough and then TVS is probably a requirement, maybe passive filters as well.

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot I have updated my answer re TVS position.

Comment: @RobinIddon thank you. During the test, the MCU still continues to count time on the TFT screen. What I saw in this test section is that the SW7, SW8 and SW9 keys press on their own and then all buttons stop working within 10-15 seconds.

Comment: But do you need the buttons to operate correctly during the EFT test?  I understand you don't want the buttons to press on their own, but what about if a user actually presses them?  The problem you have is that each input and output is either logic high or logic low depending on MCU scanning and also EFT induced currents.  It is impossible with this simple scheme for MCU to determine whether the received logic level is due to EFT noise or actual button press.  You may need a more sophisticated scheme.  For example modulate the COLUMNx and make sure LINEx returns same pattern.

Comment: But even then, when EFT is running the noise might prevent proper switch detection.

Answer (score 1):

There often is a rectifier effect at the input of integrated circuits. The internal protection diodes rectify RF signals coupled into wires. The IC sometimes reads this as logic high level.

I added R1 as pulldown to define the input level if nothing else is connected, but the simulator shows in the time domain analysis, that this resistor value may be too big under some conditions.

The gate capacitance integrates the rectified signal and the FET turns on. This FET circuit is just an example, not a real IC internal circuit.

If you add a capacitor (C2) between the data line and GND, C1 and C2 form a capacitive divider and the RF amplitude is too small for rectification.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVROb2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your comments.